# Processing python triggers....giving errors during installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using x86_32 computer with Linux 10.04.
Installing ROS Electric.

During the very end of completion of the "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full" command I got python trigger errors.

Before proceeding, I'd like to know if these are ok and if not, what to do about fixing them. Since I may be using python along with c++, the python errors concern me. Here are the errors:

```
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Compiling /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/leo/plugins/ConceptualSort.py ...
SyntaxError: ("unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'lcsort2' it is a nested function",)

Compiling /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/leo/plugins/LeoN.py ...
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/leo/plugins/LeoN.py', 222, 41, '        if is_causally_ready(t_op, self): \t\t# check if it is causally ready\n'))

Processing triggers for python-central ...
```

Thanks for your support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45012/processing-python-triggers....giving-errors-during-installation/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with ros. It seems like some non-ros python libraries you installed are broken.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1